# Remember Variable gets reset once I press on the second Button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I click on first Button multiple times which changes text Variable and once I press second button changed text Variable is shown with changed value.

But if I uncomment Text View text Variable gets reset once I press on the second Button.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Commented Text View (WORKING)
[image]

Uncommented Text View (NOT WORKING)
[image]

```
package com.example.testcompose

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

//==========================================================
// MAIN ACTIVITY
//==========================================================
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {

      var text = remember{ "Hello " }              //Remembered but not observed
      var state by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }  //Remembered and     observed

      Column {

        Button({
          text += "you "
          Log.d("PRINT", text)
        }) {
          Text("Increase Text")
        }
        
        Button({state++}) { Text("Button was clicked $state times $text")  }
        
        //Text("Button was clicked $state times $text")
        
      }

    }
  }
}
```